# ImportError: No module named caffe - I don't know how to install caffe for Anaconda on Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, caffe

i have been attempting to follow [this tutorial](http://thirdeyesqueegee.com/deepdream/2015/07/19/running-googles-deep-dream-on-windows-with-or-without-cuda-the-easy-way/) to install Google DeepDream, but unfortunately i have run into many problems. My first being that i needed to create a new python 2.7 environment for Anaconda as my root python was 3.5 which didn't seem to be co-operating with DeepDream. This meant i had to install numpy, scipy, PIL and protobuf manually for the py27 env but i don't know how to install caffe. I downloaded the caffe files from github, downloaded CMake and tried to compile it but i have no idea what i'm doing and have never done this before. Does anyone know how i can install caffe for Anaconda 3 for my py27 environment on Windows 10?

Comment: Have you considered using a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, i tried that but i did not like the slow speed and lack of control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question I'm noticing two likely issues with your installation. The first is that

Caffe is not really intended to be installed. The normal usecase is to compile it locally after tweaking it's settings to best match your system. I believe the tutorial you are using comes with a precompiled version, but for better performance I eventually replaced it with my own compilation of [Microsoft Caffe](https://github.com/microsoft/caffe). Be forwarned though: Microsoft/Caffe only works in VS2013 and has a lot of weird issues with NuGet not handling it's dependencies correctly.

Secondly as to how to deploy a compiled copy of caffe with pycaffe the default for deepdream is under '../caffe/' as in one directory up and in it's own folder, but you can adjust the code in dream.ipynb to point to anywhere you would like to place caffe.